# state machine performes just for one pattern

Tags: vhdl

I have stuck on this problem since last week and tried to receive a correct answer from different ways but unfortunately since now it has not worked. 
I hae a state machine that receives three patterns and make a matrix for each one of them and then sum all of them together and sends it to output. But the state machine sends the matrix of first pattern to output.
I think the problem is that adder should work with the clock  (state one) and state machine goes to the next state with event edge of each clock, therefore it can't synchronize with the adder. But i don't know how i can fix this problem. I would appriciate any help kindly.

P.S The package must be included in the code.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Company: 
-- Engineer: 
-- 
-- Create Date:    14:11:16 0NUMBITS-1/11/2012 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    state_machine - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_SIGNED.ALL;
use work.my_data_types.all;

---- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
---- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity state_machine2 is
port(
        pattern      : in std_logic_vector(0 to NUMBITS-1);                 --The incorrect pattern
        clk          : in std_logic;
        result       : out matrix2D(0 to NUMBITS-1, 0 to NUMBITS-1)
     );     
end state_machine2;

architecture Behavioral of state_machine2 is

    type state is (zero , one, two);
    signal pr_state, nx_state : state ;
    signal s_out_matrix     : matrix2D(0 to NUMBITS-1, 0 to NUMBITS-1);
    signal s_flipflop_adder : matrix2D(0 to NUMBITS-1, 0 to NUMBITS-1):= (others => (others => (others => '0')));
    signal q                : integer;

begin

    process(clk)
    begin
        if(clk'event and clk = '1')then
            pr_state <= nx_state;
        end if;
    end process;

    process(pattern, pr_state)

        variable cnt:     integer := -1;        
    begin

    case pr_state is
        when zero =>
            q <= 0;                                        -- state number
            if(cnt < NUM_TRAIN_PATTERN)then
                cnt := cnt + 1;
                nx_state <= one;
            else
                nx_state <= two;
            end if;

        when one =>
            q <= 1;
    For i in 0 to NUMBITS-1 loop                                    --The multiplication in the pattern
        For j in 0 to NUMBITS-1 loop                                                    
            if(i = j) then
                s_out_matrix(i,j) <= (others => '0');
            elsif(pattern(i) = pattern(j)) then
                s_out_matrix(i,j) <= (0 => '1', others => '0');
            else 
                s_out_matrix(i,j) <= (others => '1');
            end if;
        end loop;
    end loop;

    if(clk'event and clk = '1')then                      -- Sum of the matrixes
        For i in 0 to NUMBITS-1 loop                        
            For j in 0 to NUMBITS-1 loop        
                s_flipflop_adder(i,j) <= s_flipflop_adder(i,j) + s_out_matrix(i,j);
            end loop;
        end loop;
    end if;
            nx_state <= zero;

        when two =>                                 
            q <= 2;
            result <= s_flipflop_adder;

            end case;
            test_q <= q;
        end process;
end Behavioral;

the package:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_SIGNED.ALL;
---- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
---- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

package my_data_types is 
    type matrix2D is array (integer range <> , integer range <> ) of signed(2 downto 0);    -- Matrix2D
    constant NUMBITS : integer := 3;
    constant NUM_TRAIN_PATTERN : natural := 3;
end my_data_types;
```

Comment: Try rewriting the state machine as a proper clocked process.

Comment: The second process is horrible. Use of variable, asynchronous state machine mixed with inline clocked stuff. Moreover the process  sensibility list doesn't even have the clk signal and the code doesn't compile. Please, refine your code before asking for help. There are a multitude of other problems or poor design with your code, but I think you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

A few thing stand out...

First of all, whenever you create a state machine, there needs to be a way to reset it, ideally an input signal which forces the sequential elements to a known state. In your case, there is no way to reset `pr_state`, and thus no way to know from the code what the starting state should be. Also, avoid "resetting" sequential elements by assigning a default value as is done for `s_flipflop_adder`, because that is likely to lead to a mismatch between simulation and actual implementation.

Second, do not generate sequential and combinatorial signals inside the same process. For each signal, decide if it is sequential (i.e. a flip flop, updated on a clock edge), or combinatorial (i.e. updated almost instantly from the value of other signals, slowed down only by the propagation delays in the logic elements). For sequential signals, create a sequential process in which everything is inside an `if rising_edge(clk)` or `if clk'event and clk = '1'` statement (equivalent for most purposes), and with only the clock (and maybe your reset signal, if it is asynchronous) in the sensitivity list. For combinatorial signals, put them in a combinatorial process, which is a process with no clock and a complete sensitivity list.

In your design, the first process is a proper sequential process. The second process, however, starts as a combinatorial process (with an incomplete sensitivity list), but then there is a sequential assignment to `s_flipflop_adder` nested in a branch of the case statement. The signal `s_flipflop_adder` is unlikely to ever be assigned because `clk` is not in the sensitivity list, and even if it was, the synthesis tools will likely not interpret that mix as you intended it.

Finally, do not use a variable to keep state information as you do with the `cnt` variable, and make sure you update your state only on a clock edge (i.e. sequentially).

With these three points in mind, the state machine will look something more akin to this (I inlined the definitions from the my_data_types package only to make the answer easier to read):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_vector_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity state_machine2 is
port(
    clk          : in std_logic;
    rst          : in std_logic;
    pattern      : in std_logic_vector(0 to NUMBITS-1);
    result       : out matrix2D(0 to NUMBITS-1, 0 to NUMBITS-1) );
end state_machine2;

architecture Behavioral of state_machine2 istype state is (zero , one, two);
    constant NUMBITS            : integer := 3;
    constant NUM_TRAIN_PATTERN  : natural := 3;
    subtype signed3 is signed(NUMBITS-1 downto 0);
    type matrix2D is array (integer range <> , integer range <> ) of signed3;

    signal pr_state         : state;
    signal s_flipflop_adder : matrix2D(0 to NUMBITS-1, 0 to NUMBITS-1);
    signal cnt              : integer;
begin
    process(clk) is
        variable add_operand : signed3;
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if rst = '1' then
                pr_state         <= zero;
                cnt              <= -1;
                s_flipflop_adder <= (others => (others => (others => '0')));
            else
                case pr_state is

                when zero =>
                    cnt <= cnt + 1;

                    if cnt < NUM_TRAIN_PATTERN then
                        pr_state <= one;
                    else
                        pr_state <= two;
                    end if;

                when one =>
                    for i in 0 to NUMBITS-1 loop
                        for j in 0 to NUMBITS-1 loop
                            if i = j then
                                add_operand := (others => '0');
                            elsif pattern(i) = pattern(j) then
                                add_operand := (0 => '1', others => '0');
                            else
                                add_operand := (others => '1');
                            end if;

                            s_flipflop_adder(i,j) <= s_flipflop_adder(i,j)
                                                   + add_operand;
                        end loop;
                    end loop;

                when two =>
                    result <= s_flipflop_adder;
                end case;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Thank you for posting this question, as these are very common mistakes.